# 404 error on trying to access FastAPI endpoints through Azure Functions Post-Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, fastapi

I am trying to host FastAPi on the Azure function app. I am able to deploy without errors, however when I try to test out the endpoint access, I am getting a 404 error.

My root folder architecture looks like this:

[image]

The Azure function code in "function_app.py" looks like this:

```
import azure.functions as func

from WrapperFunction import app as fastapi_app

app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fastapi_app, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
```

The Azure function code imports the FastAPI app from the "Wrapper Function" folder. The FastAPI app code is written in a "**init**.py" file in the "Wrapper Function" folder and looks like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
origins = ["*"]

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/sample")
def read_sample():
    return{'Hello':'Sample'}
```

The "host.json" file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 4.0.0]"
  },
  "extensions": 
  {
    "http": 
    {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I am basically trying to follow the exact procedure given on the page : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/.
When trying to access the deployed azure function through http://.azurewebsites.net/, it works sand shows me that the function app is up and running.

However, on trying to access the FastAPI endpoint through "/sample" for instance (http://.azurewebsites.net/sample), it's throwing me a 404 error.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into similar, I had to add a setting in the Azure portal under 'Configuration' in the function application, according to the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators#update-app-settings